# Ios build failing Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMLogger

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am making a build for `ios` using `Cordova`. But it is giving the error:

> Ios build failing Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_GSDK_GTMLogger

I removed pods and installed them again in the ios repo of the project name/platforms. I cleaned the build after doing so. Also, I removed the DerivedData once.

Moreover, I worked on many things which I found on Google. I am looking for an instant response, please help if any of you can?

I am using these three in the package.json:

```
"cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated-apns": "^1.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this :
To anyone wondering, I solved it by downgrading to

`"cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1",`
Latest version 8.0.0 is using Pods to manage dependencies which will be global/project-wide, while 7.0.1 handles dependencies locally i.e only for that plugin. So it won't affect any other plugin(s) using those same dependencies.